# Formatting latex code in lyx

Tags: math-mode, formatting, lyx, line-breaking, lyx-layouts

I have been using lyx and have run into text formatting issues when using math inline formulas. For example, the code bellow:

[image: lyx inline math formula]

is converted to:

[image: pdf inline math formula]

How can I make the formula fit the numbered list?

Comment: LaTeX breaks equations when it encounters a relation or binary operation. Here you don't have them. You can write "\mathrel{}" in the middle, and then it will break it when necessary.

Comment: what you are expressing here isn't really math -- and you really want to use "regular" italic for the word *software* to avoid the incorrect spacing around the *f*. you can use math notation for the angle brackets, then mark what's inside it as text: `$\langle$\textit{software},\textit{timestamp}, \textit{hash}(\textit{software})$\rangle$`.  yes, marking up every word separately is a pain, but the commas and especially parentheses should remain upright in such "meta" notation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments